# Is it possible to 'watch' attributes' changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to "watch" for ui changes on the directive? 
something like that:

```
.directive('vValidation', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.$watch(function() {
            if (this.hasClass('someClass')) console.log('someClass added');
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Yes. You can use `attr.$observe` if you use interpolation at the attribute.

But if this is not an interpolated attribute and you expect it to be changed from somewhere else in the application (what is extremely not recommended, read [Common Pitfalls](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)), than you can `$watch` a function return:

```js
scope.$watch(function() {
    return element.attr('class'); 
}, function(newValue){
    // do stuff with newValue
});
```

Anyway, its probably that the best approach for you would be change the code that changes the element class. Which moment does it get changed?

Comment: I just need a directive restricted to an attribute, and when I add the directive to any arbitrary element, it should be able to tell when other attributes of that arbitrary element have changed. In my case it's `class`

Comment: modifying the code that changes class would be somehow unacceptable solution for me, although probably the rightest thing to do. I still need to intercept somehow the moment when it changes the class

Comment: Then go with the `$watch` I've posted. It will give what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to use your solution, but I can't make it work. Would you please show me some sample? excuse me if I'm asking too much - jsfiddle would be great though

Comment: [Here it go](http://plnkr.co/edit/H6pA4kIWDPLX4zT7QRRe?p=preview). Again, **try to gain control over the change moment**. If you can't, then see my code. Remember you need to invoke an `_rootScope.$apply()` (stored at MainController) in order to Angular take notes from change. The toggle logic is in `index.html`, the last `script` tag. And the `app.js` contains the Angular code.

Comment: For guys who still play with Angular 1.x - "But if this is not an interpolated attribute and you expect it to be changed from somewhere else in the application (what is extremely not recommended, read Common Pitfalls" - Not sure if this is correct interpretation here. If you will look into i.e. ng-if implementation how angulat build it, its exactly what they do there. So its more I think 'if you know what you are doing' then 'extreamly not recommended' and can be misleading a little bit.

Answer (score 41):

```
attrs.$observe('class', function(val){});
```

Comment: hmmm. can you post a JSFiddle? Not sure what problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: Since you are doing it outside of the Angular "boundry", Angular is not going to know, also adding UI code in Controllers is not the way to go. If you are trying to create a Validation solution, please refer to the validation guide on the AngularJS.

Comment: you're right. I'm trying to marry asp.net helpers, jquery.validate-unobrusive and angular. Seems that not easy as it looks

Answer (score 2):

You can also watch variable in the controller.

This code automatically hides notification bar after some other module displays the feedback message.

**HTML:**

```
<notification-bar
    data-showbar='vm.notification.show'>
        <p> {{ vm.notification.message }} </p>
</notification-bar>
```

**DIRECTIVE:**

```
var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        showbar: '=showbar',
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/views/partials/notification.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $scope.$watch('showbar', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            //console.log('showbar changed:', newValue);
            hide_element();
        }, true);

        function hide_element() {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.showbar = false;
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
};
```

**DIRECTIVE TEMPLATE:**

```
<div class="notification-bar" data-ng-show="showbar"><div>
    <div class="menucloud-notification-content"></div>
```