# Angular Polymer data-binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, polymer, web-component

I want to make two way data binding between Polymer and Angular, for this I am using [Angu-poly](https://github.com/matjaz/angu-poly) library.

Here is a link to an example which is working, while passing strings via name and age attributes: [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNKlEYiIPVYqbR7yiWJg?p=preview).

```
<x-kid bind-polymer ng-repeat="kid in kids" angupoly="{name:'kid.name', age:'kid.age'}">
</x-kid>
```

But when I try to make it with passing an object via kid attribute, it seems that something goes wrong, here is the link: [not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lsD1rGxt6P6P9h7EoZo?p=preview).

```
<x-kid bind-polymer angupoly="{kid:'kid'}">
</x-kid>
```

What should I do to make it work?

**Update:**
Also tried it with this [library](https://github.com/eee-c/angular-bind-polymer) and it didn't work. the code will look like this:

```
<x-kid bind-polymer kid={{kid}}>
</x-kid>
```

**Big Update:**
Here I made some progress tweaking the ["angular-bind-polymer"](https://github.com/eee-c/angular-bind-polymer) library. For now I am able to bind objects from outside polymer into polymer, [here is the updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q67Pbd98pNqTKUzXw5Rm?p=preview). The problem now is to do this in the other direction.
*Note:* I am getting some exception from angular side, take a look maybe you can help to solve it. **I think we are very close :)**.

Comment: Having the same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181605/polymer-web-component-attribute-value-not-getting-passed-down). A workaround I found was to create an attribute listener e.g. `angupolyChanged: function(n,o){//set stuff}` to set values. But changes are not propagating out of the component yet...

Comment: check out following project for double binding. I just had some success with this yesterday: https://github.com/GabiAxel/ng-polymer-elements

Comment: I'm trying to bind to backbone models, do you think it will be possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816912/how-to-bind-backbone-model-to-polymer-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated example http://plnkr.co/w1icAU

With Polymer 1.0 two way binding is much simpler and also able to bind objects not just string values.

Here is the main part

```
<x-kid ng-repeat="kid in ::kids" angupoly="{name:'kid.name', age:'kid.age'}"></x-kid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of some kind of reference.

How should I explain, just like you work with object in scope in data binding. when you update the object to a new object, the UI will not update with new object values.

Comment: Why not? Angular directives works this way, I expect the same from polymer components...

Answer (score 1):

It looks that [Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) is THE answer, excerpt:

> Our goal is to deliver a lean, lightweight set of AngularJS-native UI elements that implement the material design system for use in Angular SPAs.

Comment: I am talking about creating my own elements. I hope angular will show how to make the data binding work in both directions.

Comment: Binding barely works for polymer elements (which implement the material design).  Things like ng-model don't bind at all (although I'm trying to hack at that).

Comment: It is working with primitives (using some libraries, you can find two of them in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find clues from [this blog](http://blog.sethladd.com/2014/02/angular-and-polymer-data-binding.html) even if its aim is for dart:

> Angular and Polymer Data Binding, Together!

Comment: Nope.... It is talking about data binding but not object data binding in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [ng-polymer](https://github.com/GabiAxel/ng-polymer-elements), this project may help give you some insight