# Polymer web component attribute value not getting passed down

Tags: angularjs, polymer, web-component

I have started out my own little [WebComponents](https://github.com/furier/WebComponents) library at [Github](https://github.com/), and it all works well by it self when tested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WebComponents</title>
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/WebComponents/components/scheduler/ss-scheduler.html">
</head>
<body>
    <ss-scheduler cronValue="0 0 0 0 *"></ss-scheduler>
</body>
</html>
```

This would render the component like this

[image]

This snippet shows how the *web component* should be used, and the [`cronValue`](https://github.com/furier/WebComponents/blob/master/components/scheduler/ss-scheduler.html#L3) is correctly picked up and used inside the *web component*.
However when I try to use the *web component* in another project I have on [Github](https://github.com/), only `null` is passed down to the *web component*.

[websync](https://github.com/furier/websync) client side uses [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) together with [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) web components.

```
<ss-scheduler cronValue="{{task.schedule.time}}" ng-class="{hidden: !task.schedule.enabled}"></ss-scheduler>
```

Here I am trying to bind a *angular scope* value to the [`cronValue`](https://github.com/furier/WebComponents/blob/master/components/scheduler/ss-scheduler.html#L3) attribute, but a log statement inside the *web component* shows that nothing is picked up.
I have added a log statement in my *directive* exposing the `task.schedule.time` value, and it is not `null`.

Somewhere in between the value is not correctly bound to the *web component* by *angular*.

I found this project while researching and trying to resolve the matter, [angular-bind-polymer](https://github.com/eee-c/angular-bind-polymer).
But that only helps changes made to the value inside the *web component* to be picked up by angular, which it also doesn't do even with this *directive*.

**I now turn to you (StackOverflow), in hopes of figuring out why the *angular web component binding* isn't working.**

**EDIT:**

I have now also tried [angu-poly](https://github.com/matjaz/angu-poly) and it's also not working.

Comment: Im not sure but I think the capital `V` in `cronValue` was the issue.
I converted the `WebComponent` to an `Angular.js` `directive` and had the same issue, after going for all lowercase `cronvalue` it started working again. I guess that was the issue for the `WebComponent` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like changing the attribute name from `cronValue` to `cronvalue` solved the issue, now `angular-bind-polymer` and `angu-poly` works just fine.

[In the *Polymer* documentation it says:](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attrcase)

> It’s worth noting that the HTML parser considers attribute names case
> insensitive. Property names in JavaScript are however case sensitive.
>
> This means that attributes can be written any way that you like, but
> if you look at an element’s attribute list, the names will always be
> lowercase. Polymer is aware of this and will attempt to match the
> attributes to properties carefully. For example, this should work as
> expected:

This is probably true for *Polymer* but together with *angular.js* the two way binding seems to fall apart and don`t work.