# Polymer-Angular two-way data binding for framework components (core-elements/paper-elements)

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I am trying to blend Polymer web components in my Angular application, but I am not being able to get the two-way data binding between these frameworks working. I've already watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1NpZ-0Op0w&index=14&list=PLRAVCSU_HVYu-zlRaqArF8Ytwz1jlMOIM) and already tried the solution provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563880/polymer-angularjs-two-way-data-binding) but it still doesn't work for me. These were my attempts:

- `Object` attribute value

  `<game-card game="{{game}}" bind-polymer></game-card>` - based on `post-card.html` on the Polymer tutorial. `game` is an object with id, title, etc.

  I created the `gameChanged` function on the web component and added a new property in the `game` variable, something like `this.game.foo = 'bar';`, but if I do

  `<pre><code>{{game | json}}</code></pre>`

  right after the component, there's no `"foo": "bar"` in the stringified object. Even with

  `publish: {
    game: {reflect: true}
  }`,

  it doesn't work.
- Framework components

  `<core-input  value="{{cool}}" bind-polymer></core-input>
   <paper-input value="{{cool}}" bind-polymer></paper-input>`

  It only works if I edit the **element's source code** to `reflect` the `value` attribute (on `core-input.html`, as paper-input extends it). I think it isn't a good way of solving this issue.

Am I missing something? Is there a good resource I can look for this Angular-Polymer integration? Searching on Google brings more results about [the material](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer) than about the library itself and, when found, most of them are "Polymer for Dart" resources.

Comment: Yep. Pretty sure core-input's value property needs to be set to `reflect: true` in order for this to work (https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/blob/master/core-input.html#L161). Otherwise, the attribute won't update and Angular's data binding system will never see a change. Maybe file a bug? https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/issues/new

Comment: @edibel I've had similar problems and it sometimes doesn't work even if the "reflect: true" is set.

Comment: @ebidel - I will file a bug as soon as possible, thanks for your response. But what about the `Object` type attribute? Isn't it supposed to add the new property to it, even more with `reflect: true`?
Another issue I came over is that when I pass the `game` variable to the attribute, sometimes my web component receives a js Object and sometimes it receives a JSON string, forcing me to `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: Are u using some third party library?

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340258/angular-polymer-data-binding

Answer (score 1):

Try with the NG Polymer Elements lib it solves the 2 way data binding of angular and polymer (core and paper elements) and some other stuff that breaks with angular/polymer, it also has the documentation to addyour own custom polymer elements to the angular binding support

[NG Polymer Elements](https://gabiaxel.github.io/ng-polymer-elements/)

Comment: This seems to be a good lib, will try it soon and see if it solves the issue (even though I will not use polymer anymore).

Comment: If youre not going to do polymer anymore .... and i really get why (its painfull to develop in that) this is a very good alternative, almost every beauty of polymer in a simple bootstrap way :) [link](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)