# How to watch for changes in attribute value modified by jQuery, using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I have an attribute `aria-valuenow` which is being modified by jQuery in the [rateit](http://rateit.codeplex.com/documentation) star rating jQuery plugin when a user does the rating or changes that rating when submitting a review form.

Following is the html snippet I use to display the stars of the plugin.

```
<div class="review">
    <input type="range" value="0" step="0.25" id="backing4">
    <div class="rateit" plugin-rate-it="{backingfld: '#backing4', resetable: 'true', ispreset: 'false', min: 0, max: 5}" data-rateit-backingfld="#backing4" data-rateit-resetable="false"  data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-min="0" data-rateit-max="5"></div>
</div>
```

In the above html `plugin-rate-it` is a directive I have that initialized the plugin, otherwise the stars are not displayed. Below is the code for the directive.

```
myApp.directive('pluginRateIt', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).rateit(scope.$eval(attrs.pluginRateIt));
        }
    };
});
```

Now, below is the html that is rendered when the page loads for the html code above. I've got it from the page's source code.

```
 <div class="review">
      <input type="range" value="0" step="0.25" id="backing4" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" style="display: none;">
      <div class="rateit" plugin-rate-it="{backingfld: '#backing4', resetable: 'true', ispreset: 'false', min: 0, max: 5}" data-rateit-backingfld="#backing4" data-rateit-resetable="false" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-min="0" data-rateit-max="5">
        <button id="rateit-reset-2" data-role="none" class="rateit-reset" aria-label="reset rating" aria-controls="rateit-range-2" style="display: none;"></button>
        <div id="rateit-range-2" class="rateit-range" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-label="rating" aria-owns="rateit-reset-2" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5" aria-valuenow="0" aria-readonly="false" style="width: 80px;     height: 16px;">
            <div class="rateit-selected rateit-preset" style="height: 16px; width: 0px; display: block;"></div>
            <div class="rateit-hover" style="height: 16px; display: none; width: 0px;">             
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

So, the only attribute that changes when the user does the rating or changes the rating is the `aria-valuenow` attribute.

Could somebody help me understand that how could I watch for the changes in the value of the `aria-valuenow` attribute, so that I could capture that value in the `ng-model` of my review form and submit it.

Comment: Can you not just set the value to a scope value? That way when the user changes the rating, it updates itself.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy: The attribute `aria-valuenow` is displayed on the html source of the page only after the page has been loaded. The RateIt jQuery plugin seems to be doing its thing to do that. I could only assign it its initial value through the `value` attribute in the `<input type="range" value="0" step="0.25" id="backing4">` element.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy: On further inspection, I figured out that is I set the value of the `value` attribute in the `input` tag to something in scope, for example, `value="{{stars}}"`, to keep in sync with the value of `aria-valuenow` attribute, thinking that it would give me the `aria-valuenow` attribute's value in `$scope` in my controller, I found out that if I do that then the `aria-valuenow` is set to 50 by the plugin for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest, hackiest way to do this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911300/is-it-possible-to-watch-attributes-changes). Essentially, write a function in a controller that checks and returns the value of `area-valuenow`. Then `$watch` its output, and do something in the callback of the watch when it changes.

Unfortunately, this means angular will be running that check-and-return function constantly. On a small app, you might get away with this.

A more angular-ish plan would be to modify the plugin so that it runs inside a controller and can modify a scope value at the same time as it is modifying the DOM. Then you can watch that scope value more efficiently.