# How to observe or watch an input attribute change in an AngularJS Service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-services

I have a radio button in my UI that has an ngModel and it enable/disable another input through ngDisabled.

I want to observer/watch/trigger when an input element become enabled/disabled and it has to be done in an Angular Service. I simply can't find how to do that. Here is how I would do it in a Directive:

```
// for the case of field that might be ng-disabled, we should skip validation
// Observe the angular disabled attribute
attrs.$observe("disabled", function(disabled) {
  if (disabled) {
    // Turn off validation when element is disabled
    cancelValidation();
  } else {
    // Re-Validate the input when enabled
    var value = ctrl.$viewValue || '';
    ctrl.$setValidity('validation', validate(value, true));
  }
});
```

But how to do it in a **Service**???

I do not wish to have another Directive, I really want it done through the Service.

Before asking the question, I found this [Is it possible to 'watch' attributes' changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911300/is-it-possible-to-watch-attributes-changes) and I tried it

```
scope.$watch(function() {return element.attr('disabled'); }, function(newValue){});
```

but that does not seem to work, at least not when I enable/disable my radio button (the input element as an ngDisabled that is bind to the radio button with an ngModel)

I also found that we could possible use jQuery.watch() but I want to stick with vanilla javascript or jqLite. Is it possible?

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned that this Service is on it's own and does not have access to the Controller, because it's a Form validation tool and it does not know about the outside (at least not more than the element itself and his scope). You can check it out and use it if you want: [Angular-Validation](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation) and it support Directive and Service depending on what or where you want the validation to happen and my problem was related to the code in the Service only. The answer from [pankajparkar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30672424/1212166) helped me solved it... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you had attribute `disabled` with an interpolation something like `disabled="{{disable}}"` that why you were able to put `$observe` on that value try changing the same thing to `$watch` will not work on that `attribute`, you need to additionally need `$interpolate` service to evaluate you attribute interpolation. So that the actually value will get evaluate is it `disabled` or `''` and if changes it state then `$watch` function will get fired accordingly.

**Code**

```
scope.$watch(function() {
   return $interpolate(element.attr('disabled'))(scope); //this will evaluate attribute value `{{}}``
}, function(newValue){
    //your code would be here
});
```

Comment: ahh right I forgot about that, it helped me to find what was my problem, I actually use `ngDisabled` and so I had to change my watch for that and instead of using interpolate, I had to use `scope.$eval(element.attr('ng-disabled'))` and now it works.. So yes your code is valid if I use directly the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: I answered on the basis of what you've asked in question.Reallly very glad to see that my solution does help you. Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a Scope is to "glue together" the presentation and the business logic of your app. It does not make much sense to pass a `$scope` into a service.
You could always do a  `$scope.$watch` at the initialisation of the controller using this service (the one associated with the view of your radio button) and trigger a call to the service to do the update you need.

---

If you can already access this variable in your service (getting it from the controller) you should be able to do :

```
app.service('myservice',function(){
    this.listen = function($scope) {
        $scope.$watch(function(){return someScopeValue},function(){
           //$scope.dosomestuff();
        });
    }
});

//your controller

function myCtrl($scope,myservice) {
    $scope.listen = function() {
        myservice.listen($scope);
    }

    //call your method
    $scope.listen();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I do have a `scope` in my Service for other reasons. But as I mentioned, I was not able to make it work with the `scope.$watch`, I want to watch an attribute change, not a value... So how would I do that? If you could send some code that does a watch of `disabled` or `ngDisabled`, I would be happy to see. Thanks

Comment: maybe try inisializing `scope` with `var scope = $rootscope.$new()` but I don't know if you can manage to watch a variable in a view from a directive, for me going thought a controller which will call your service is much cleaner.

Comment: My problem is not to get the scope, my problem is how to watch the disabled attribute...

Comment: I updated my response, hope it helps but without seeing more code I cannot help more sorry :/

Comment: Oh ok I see why you did that, that is following the observers pattern and doing a push, but unfortunately I don't have access to the Controller so I can't do a push, I need to do a pull as an observer. So I really need to watch, I can't just advise of a change by my own. You are right I should provide more code or at least mention that it is a validation Service that does not have access to the Controller (it's an open source tool for Form, you check it out [Angular-Validation](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation). Thanks for the effort, it helps ;)