# Watching a controller $scope property set by directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive which sets an attribute which is bind to a controller $scope property which I watch. The problem is that the watcher is never trigger and I'm wandering why.

**Update!**

**The Solution**

After more digging I found this cool article by Jim Hoskins about $scope.$apply() which solve my problem.

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

```js
mod.directive('gsGridSorting', function($modal, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var lastSortedCol;
            $element.on('click', 'th.sorting', function (event) {
                var target = $(event.target);
                //The missing piece!
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.sortColumn =  target.data('column');
                })
            });
        },
        scope: {
            sortColumn: '='
        }
    };
});

<thead gs-grid-sorting sort-column="sortColumn"> ... </thead>
```

Watching my $scope property without success.

```js
$scope.$watch('sortColumn', function (oldValue, newValue) {

});
```

Comment: Looks like you're watching an attribute.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911300/is-it-possible-to-watch-attributes-changes

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to watch `sortColumn` or `sortDir`? Cause your 2 code fragments are different

Comment: Yes, but I'm watching it from my controller, the other post is when you want to watch it from the directive.

Comment: @user2341963 sorry, I'm trying to watch sortColumn, but I got really frustrated by not making it work so I forgot to delete some osboslete code.

Comment: Why can't you watch it your directive and bind a callback to the scope or something?

Comment: When you call `$attrs.$set('sortColumn' ...` you are just changing the value of your html attribute 'sort-column', not the model 'sortColumn'.

So when you click your element, your html markup actually changes to:

    `<thead gs-grid-sorting sort-column="WHATEVER target.data('column') RETURNS"> ... </thead>`. If you want to see the change then you have to set the value in your directive `$scope.sortColumn = target.data('column')` and your model should the attribute of an object like : '<thead gs-grid-sorting sort-column="param.sortColumn">'

Comment: I try this but without success. In my controller the $watch didn't get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `$watch` with a function same follow code:

```
mod.directive('gsGridSorting', function($modal, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var lastSortedCol;

            $element.on('click', 'th.sorting', function (event) {
                var target = $(event.target);
                $attrs.sortColumn = target.data('column');
            });
            $scope.$watch (function(){
                return $attrs.sortColumn;
            },function(oldValue,newValue){
                console.log(newValue);
            });
        },
        scope: {
            sortColumn: '='
        }
    };
});
```